# How to return only specific attributes when using Sequelize Create method

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have been searching through Sequelize documentation and forums for the correct syntax and it seems I am doing it the right way, but for some reason the password field is still being returned in the response payload...

The following link shows the attributes exclude syntax I am using was added in version 3.11 of Sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4074

Anyone know what I might be missing here? Below is the `Create` method and the console log from the `Insert` statement.

**`Create` method**

```
async create(req, res) {
try {
    let user = await User.create({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }, {
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['password']
        }
    });

    console.log("USER: ", user);

    res.status(201).send(user.toJSON());
}
catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error)
};
```

}

**Console Log**

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users"
>   ("id","firstName","lastName","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt")
>   VALUES
>   (DEFAULT,'James','Martineau','test@gmail.com','$2b$10$7ANyHzs74OXYfXHuhalQ3ewaS4DDem1cHMprKaIa7gO434rlVLKp2','2019-02-28
>   15:18:15.856 +00:00','2019-02-28 15:18:15.856 +00:00') RETURNING *;
>
> USER:  User {    dataValues:
>       { id: 6,
>         firstName: 'James',
>         lastName: 'Martineau',
>         email: 'test@gmail.com',
>         password:
>          '$2b$10$7ANyHzs74OXYfXHuhalQ3ewaS4DDem1cHMprKaIa7gO434rlVLKp2',
>         updatedAt: 2019-02-28T15:18:15.856Z,
>         createdAt: 2019-02-28T15:18:15.856Z }...

Comment: i'm still looking for this like you needed. You finded one way to do this without property.delete? delete all my properties seems not to be a dry solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in the [document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-create), you can't exclude attributes when you **create** a model. Only exclude when you **find** a model.

I suggest:

```js
async create(req, res);
{
    try {
        let user = await User.create({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        delete user["password"];//delete field password
        console.log("USER: ", user);

        res.status(201).send(user.toJSON());
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    };
}
```

Comment: Here was the final result
`delete user.dataValues.password`

Querying the database again to get the specific attributes would be more costly.

Answer (score 10):

The proper way to handle this is to leverage the afterCreate and afterUpdate hooks on the actual data model, that Sequelize exposes. These hooks are fired after the record is persisted, so any mutations to the dataValues will only be reflected in the return.

```
sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
        id: { type: DataType.UUID, defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4, primaryKey: true },
        username: { type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false },
        password: { type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false }
    },
    {
        hooks: {
            afterCreate: (record) => {
                delete record.dataValues.password;
            },
            afterUpdate: (record) => {
                delete record.dataValues.password;
            },
        }
    }
);
```

Here is a link to the documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html

Comment: Better solution and practical approach

Answer (score 2):

```js
 User.create(req.body).then(user => {
    delete user.dataValues.password
    res.json(user)
  }).catch(error => {
   // do something with error
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try overloading Sequelize Model class with your desired functionality. For example, run following code once during application bootstrap:

```js
import {Model} from 'sequelize';

const toJSON = Model.prototype.toJSON;

Model.prototype.toJSON = function ({attributes = []} = {}) {
    const obj = toJSON.call(this);

    if (!attributes.length) {
      return obj;
    }

    return attributes.reduce((result, attribute) => {
      result[attribute] = obj[attribute];

      return result;
    }, {});
  };
```

After that, you can use your code as usual, but with an `attributes` option:

`User.toJSON({attributes: ['name', 'etc...']})`.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but it's a problem i faced recently.
The way I solved this, is like this:

```
try {
    const { firstName, lastName, email } = await User.create({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    })
    const user = { firstName, lastName, email }

}

     console.log("USER: ", user);

     res.status(201).send(user.toJSON());
}
catch (error) {
     res.status(500).send(error)
};
```

You can instantiate the fields you want like this, at least it's what i'm doing everywhere in my code

hope this works for you too :)

Answer (score 1):

With a quick read through the docs, it seems `attributes` is only mentioned within queries like:

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: { exclude: ['baz'] }
});
```

(http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#attributes)

If you want to exclude `password` with `create`, you could do something like:

```
let user = await User.create({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
}, {
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']
});
```

(http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#creating-persistent-instances)

Comment: Thanks Scott, but I don't think your response is correct. The documentation seems to state that the `fields` parameter dictates what fields will be set. This further makes sense as when i attempted to implement your suggestion by Sequelize User model blew up because the password was not provided, only the 3 fields defined were.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misunderstood your intent. Have you tried: `User.create({
 //...
{include: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']}
})`?

Comment: The include parameter is used for model associations. Since this is simply a Create function and no associations are being added here, the include parameter would not be appropriate.

I am basically trying to add the `attributes` parameter for the Sequelize.create but apparently there's a different way to do it...?

Comment: Hmm...the only thing I can think of now is to first `create` then query for the same record with `findOne` and return that. That way you can use `attributes` to `exclude` `password`.

Comment: Seems like it should also be possible to use `findOrCreate`; e.g., `let [user] = await User.findOrCreate({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }, {
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['password']
        }
    });`
Let me know if that works and I'll gladly edit the answer.